# Why is binding to "Self" not working?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, relativesource

I try to bind the control's `Tag` property to the control's `Visibility` property, but I receive the following error in VS:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

The XAML is like below:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="NavButtonSide" 
             Tag="7"  
             Visibility="{Binding Path=Tag, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource ControlTagVisibilityConverter}, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post your Converter code?

Comment: Markup is correct, either your static resource isn't being created, or (more likely) there is something going on in the converter. You should post that code too

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong with your binding. This works fine for me;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ControlTagVisibilityConverter x:Key="ControlTagVisibilityConverter" /> 
</Window.Resources>

<RadioButton 
    Tag="7" 
    Visibility="{Binding Path=Tag, 
        Converter={StaticResource ControlTagVisibilityConverter}, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
```

ControlTagVisibilityConverter.cs

```
public class ControlTagVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var valueAsString = (string) value;
        var valueAsInt = int.Parse(valueAsString);

        switch (valueAsInt)
        {
            case 7:
                return Visibility.Visible;
            default:
                return Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: my code is as same as yours. Though it works as design, but VS always show "object reference not set to an instance of an object" is xaml and this will break the Design View

Comment: The designer in visual studio 2012 is a bit fickle when it comes to assemblies that need compiling. If you have a static resource in the same project and the project needs compiling, it'll usually complain in the design view. Also look at Build Output, not errors...

Comment: I googled a lot about this issue. It seems a bug of VS. Anyway, thank u for your answer!